# How To create a stored procedure for SQL Server from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SQL server from a C# winforms application.
This is the function I have so far.

```
public void CreateStoredProcedure(string SPname)
{
        try
        {
            string query = "CREATE PROCEDURE " + SPname + " AS SELECT * FROM People WHERE Address='Mumbai'";
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "EXEC " + query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Am I doing this right? I get an error message every time I try to achieve this.

Hey thanks a lot guys!! Its working now..
This is the code that finally did it..

```
 public void CreateStoredProcedure(string SPname)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "CREATE PROCEDURE " + SPname + " AS SELECT * FROM People WHERE Address='Mumbai'";
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
        }

        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the error message? And `CommandType.Text` is by default.

Comment: Oh yes, "SPname" is the name of the stored procedure that I am trying to create.

Comment: "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."

Comment: Use `command.Connection = connection;` . You didn't connect your `SqlCommand` with your `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Everytime I try to change the code, I get different error messages. I have a table in SQL server and I want to get the rows where the Address is Mumbai.

Comment: I tried var command = new SqlCommand(connection); however there is that red line underneath connection..its supposed to be a string i guess

Comment: Yeah, it was wrong. `SqlCommand` doesn't have a constructor takes just an `SqlConnection`. Use `command.Connection = connection;` instead.

Comment: So, read the error message and fix it. Do not behave like someone who can not read. Expecially when you do basic mistakes - like not setting a connection. A tutorial may be in order, please.

Comment: Hey I am a newbie in C#. And at one point even you were. There are things that you can miss at times and it becomes difficult to understand what the error message is trying to say. I apologize if my question or the resolutions I tried were not clear enough. And if someday I become an expert and a newbie asks me something, I will do whatever it takes to point him in the right direction. We are programmers and the internet is our domain. Its our duty to pass on whatever knowledge, little or plenty, to the younger generations to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need EXEC when creating a stored procedure
and you need an active connection

Answer (score 0):

Initialize connection property of your command:

```
            command.Connection = connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a Stored Procedure using Common Language Run-time integration in stead of doing it on the fly.

**[How to: Create and Run a SQL Server Stored Procedure by using Common Language Run-time Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5czye81z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

[Deploy CLR Stored Procedure to database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dahcx0ww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In your attempt above the code will only be able to run as a once off as it contains a CREATE command. It must then change to ALTER there after or you need to drop it every time and re-created. this would not be the best practice but just keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a connection object and link it with the command object

```
    CommandObject.Connection= ConnectionObject;
```

Also the CommandType.Text is by default.

You could also check if you connection is open using

```
    if(ConnectionObject.State== ConncetionState.Closed)
       {
        ConnectionObject.Open();
        }
```

If it is closed, you will need an active Open connection to pass a query.